# ASP.net Link Button PostBackUrl not working on IIS 8

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis-8

I am using VS 2012 to develop a web application which uses the following code inside the PostBackUrl of Link button to redirect to a `About.aspx` page.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LnkSelect" CommandName="Select" Text="Image" PostBackUrl='<%# "~/About.aspx?Log_ID=" + Eval("Log_ID") %>' runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Everything working correctly when tested on localhost developement server. But when i host the web application on IIS 8, nothing happens when lik button is clicked.
Thanks in advance.

Here is the HTML of LinkButton

```
<a id="MainContent_GridView1_LnkSelect_0" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl02$LnkSelect", "", false, "", "About.aspx?Log_ID=1", false, true))">Image</a>
```

**Solution**

Converted the project to .NET 4.0 and everything working.

Comment: What is the rendered generated HTML?

Comment: Go "View source" in your browser and copy and paste here the HTML that is generated by the `<asp:LinkButton>`.

Comment: i have edited my question with HTML generated for LinkButton

Answer (score 0):

If *About.aspx* is also in your directory try this :

```
PostBackUrl='<%# "About.aspx?Log_ID=" + Eval("Log_ID") %>
```

instead of

```
PostBackUrl='<%# "~/About.aspx?Log_ID=" + Eval("Log_ID") %>
```